# compiling xerces-c++ program with Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gnu-make, xerces-c

I am trying to program with xerces-c on windows.

I have successfully built the library and compiled a simple program with success, barebone, with just cmd and notepad. However when I tried to move things to eclipse, things got a bit out of hand.

By simply having a c++ helloworld sample, then including the include files into the project path and build, eclipse is refusing to build the project, generating a lot of error, which I think mostly related to the namespace.

The errors goes as follow:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -I...blablabla -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\helloworld.o" "..\\src\\helloworld.cpp" 
gcc -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\includes\\xercesc\\util\\RefStackOf.o" "..\\src\\includes\\xercesc\\util\\RefStackOf.c"
..\src\includes\xercesc\util\RefStackOf.c:30:1: error: unknown type name 'XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_BEGIN'
 XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_BEGIN

..\src\includes\xercesc\util\RefStackOf.c:35:10: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '<' token
 template <class TElem>
      ^
..\src\includes\xercesc\util\RefStackOf.c:44:10: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '<' token
 template <class TElem> RefStackOf<TElem>::~RefStackOf()
..\src\includes\xercesc\util\RefStackOf.c:...
...this and that, this and that.... and finally...
..\src\includes\xercesc\util\RefStackOf.c:160:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' at end of input
 XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_END
```

and if I removed the file in error, error will just pop up to another file with the same format, beginning with "I dunno what XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_BEGIN means"

I have also tried using another builder, say mingw32-make, but it also generates error in the same format. Only changing the title a bit, and perhaps the files are compiled in different order, starting with this:

```
mingw32-make all
'Building file: ../src/includes/xercesc/util/BaseRefVectorOf.c'
'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
gcc -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/includes/xercesc/util/BaseRefVectorOf.d" -MT"src/includes/xercesc/util/BaseRefVectorOf.o" -o "src/includes/xercesc/util/BaseRefVectorOf.o" "../src/includes/xercesc/util/BaseRefVectorOf.c"
../src/includes/xercesc/util/BaseRefVectorOf.c:24:1: error: unknown type name 'XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_BEGIN'
XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_BEGIN
```

I am guessing that the build program does not understand how to replace the

XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_BEGIN, with

namespace XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE { }
namespace xercesc = XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE;

But I don't know of a way to teach the builder how to do this, nor I am sure if I have compiled the library in the correct way.

Can someone point me in some direction as to how to solve this? I can compile a simple program by just using cmd, so certainly I should be able to do it in Eclipse.

background:

- OS: Windows 8 64bit
- compiler: mingw-w64 5.3.0 posix-seh-rev0
- lib compiled with msys
- lib compilation command:
- ./configure --prefix=/specific-location --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-netaccessor-winsock --enable-transcoder-windows --disable-pretty-make
- make LDFLAGS=-no-undefined
- make check
- make install

cmd compilation command: g++ -Llib -Iinclude -o b.exe test.cpp

so you can see that I have also included every xerces-c header into the compiler with the -Iinclude command, so I reckon that g++ should not produce error when invoked in Eclipse, not that I know anything if its gcc.

simple program that ran when simply compiled with cmd:

```
//test.cpp
#include <xercesc/parsers/XercesDOMParser.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>
#include <xercesc/sax/HandlerBase.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/XMLString.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace xercesc;

int main (int argc, char* args[]) {

    try {
        XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
    }
    catch (const XMLException& toCatch) {
        char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.getMessage());
        cout << "Error during initialization! :\n"
             << message << "\n";
        XMLString::release(&message);
        return 1;
    }

    XercesDOMParser* parser = new XercesDOMParser();
    parser->setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);
    parser->setDoNamespaces(true);    // optional

    ErrorHandler* errHandler = (ErrorHandler*) new HandlerBase();
    parser->setErrorHandler(errHandler);

    char* xmlFile = "x1.xml";

    try {
        parser->parse(xmlFile);
        DOMDocument* xmlDoc = parser->getDocument();
        DOMElement* elementRoot = xmlDoc->getDocumentElement();
        if( !elementRoot ) throw(std::runtime_error( "empty XML document" ));
        DOMNodeList* children = elementRoot->getChildNodes();
        const  XMLSize_t nodeCount = children->getLength();
        cout << nodeCount << " nodes\n";
    }
    catch (const XMLException& toCatch) {
        char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.getMessage());
        cout << "Exception message is: \n"
             << message << "\n";
        XMLString::release(&message);
        return -1;
    }
    catch (...) {
        cout << "Unexpected Exception \n" ;
        return -1;
    }

    delete parser;
    delete errHandler;
    return 0;
}
```

@EDIT

After further investigation, it seems that the XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_BEGIN is handled in preprocessor, but its only defined in the file `util/XercesDefs.hpp`

In the files with compilation error, they always begin with

```
#if defined(XERCES_TMPLSINC)
#include <xercesc/util/RefStackOf.hpp> //or include anything else blablabla, which ultimately leads to XercesDefs.hpp
#endif
```

I searched through the entire build directory for the string XERCES_TMPLSINC, it was contained in 44 .c or .hpp files, but everyone of them is `#if !defined(XERCES_TMPLSINC)` <===== WRONGWRONG , so like XERCES_TMPLSINC was never actually defined.

According to some [forum post](http://apache-xml-project.6118.n7.nabble.com/compiler-defines-xercesc-2-8-td40201.html), XERCES_TMPLSINC was required for some old c compilers, so does anyone know how to fix this in my build? how could I define XERCES_TMPLSINC in the project? I have tried adding `#define XERCES_TMPLSINC` to the helloworld file but it still does not work.

@EDIT

my bad, actually all the .c files contained `#if defined(XERCES_TMPLSINC)` and all hpp files were `#if !defined(XERCES_TMPLSINC)`, this definitely seems a c and c++ thing?

Comment: Interesting that those files have a .c extension. They seem to contain C++ templates. Anyway, Eclipse sees .c and attempts to compile with GCC, a C compiler, rather than g++, needed to get those fun `template` goodies. Don't have a good work around for you, but hopefully this will help you search for one.

Comment: @user4581301 Thankyou for your idea. I just tried replacing the c compiler in eclipse from gcc to g++, and even when it gave command like g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/includes/xercesc/util/BaseRefVectorOf.d" -MT"src/includes/xercesc/util/BaseRefVectorOf.o" -o "src/includes/xercesc/util/BaseRefVectorOf.o" "../src/includes/xercesc/util/BaseRefVectorOf.c", it is still giving the same error, I will try to further investigate

Answer (score 1):

I was able to compile it in Ecliplse (on Linux) by adding the following `preprocessor defs` in `g++`:

`-DXERCESC_INCLUDE_GUARD_WEAVEPATH_CPP -DXERCES_HAVE_STDINT_H -DXERCES_TMPLSINC.`

On Windows I think you should substitute the with

`-DXERCES_HAVE_STDINT_H -DXERCES_HAVE_CSTDINT`